# ionic serve: events.js:72 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: cordova, networking, vagrant, ionic-framework, ports

After installing Ionic Box to try to fix issues with cordova plugins, I get these errors for ionic serve etc. (I've already shutdown all the VMs, afaik.

The ports 8100, 35729 are mentions, but they seem to not be used:

netstat -p tcp | grep  //returns nothing

```
RoverMR:build_feed rover$ ionic serve
Gulp startup tasks: [ 'sass', 'watch' ]
Running dev server: http://localhost:8100
Running live reload server: http://localhost:35729
Watching : [ 'www/**/*', '!www/lib/**/*' ]
Ionic server commands, enter:
restart or r to restart the client app from the root
goto or g and a url to have the app navigate to the given url
consolelogs or c to enable/disable console log output
serverlogs or s to enable/disable server log output
quit or q to shutdown the server and exit

events.js:72
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
Error: spawn ENOENT
at errnoException (child_process.js:1011:11)
at Process.ChildProcess.handle.onexit (childprocess.js:802:34)
RoverMR:build_feed rover$
```

Answer (score 3):

I was missing `gulp` for `gulp sass`

Just install:

```
npm install -g gulp
```

Comment: Nice, answer your own question.